# symfony access object from other controller

Tags: php, symfony

Hi i have 2 (or more) controller my main controller is:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{token}")
     */
    public function indexAction($token)
    {
        $bot = $this->container->get('telegram_bot_api');
        $bot->changeBot($token, 'bot');

        return new Response("hello word");
    }
}
```

i want to access bot object in another controller but i don't want to use `forward()` because i have to create action like `T1Action($bot)` or `T2Action($bot)`

how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have access to the application service container, you can just fetch the service from the container:

```
class DifferentController extends Controller
{
    public function differentAction()
    {
        $bot = $this->container->get('telegram_bot_api');

        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively - and in my opinion, that would be the better choice - you could wire up your controller as a service and inject the bot as a dependency via constructor.

For reference, see:

- https://qafoo.com/blog/057_containeraware_considered_harmful.html

Comment: but this method have to run whit route `/{token}` this is telegram bot webhook

Comment: I left out the route annotation because I know nothing about your application, nor your routing. Maybe it would help if you shared the other controllers, or at least the actions where you want to make use of the same service. Regardless, the main point is that you can fetch the bot from the application service container anywhere you have access to the container. This is powerful, but requires a lot of mocking when testing. Therefore, injecting dependencies via constructor is the better alternative (not judging, though).

Comment: i make my main controller like this: 

`$bot = $this->container->get('telegram_bot_api');
     $bot->changeBot('310491898:AAGo2EBRaf083tH0gD8beESDhWW-1rEpMS4', 'bot');

     new TestController($bot);

     return new Response("hello word");`
and in my TestController i have this code:
`class TestController extends DefaultController
{
 private $bot;
 public function __construct($bot) {
  $this->bot = $bot;
 }

 public function indexAction()
    {
     var_dump($this->bot->getMe());
        return;
    }
}`

is it true way?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you elaborate?

Comment: in my application method `changeBot($token)` set with token taken from url like `example.com/{token}` and in main controller set bot object i need this object in other controllers